# How do I calculate RMSD between two matrices?

Tags: statistics

I want to obtain RMSD of two matrices. I specifically want to obtain RMSD values column by column. I am confused by the denominator that will be used for the RMSD. I will use mock data to demonstrate my point. In reality, the data sets are huge.

The first data may look like the following. 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1    &2    &3   &4 \\
    2    &0.5  &6   &0.2 \\
    0.1  &0.01 &4   &0.0001
\end{bmatrix}$$
The second data looks like the following.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    5    &100    &0.2  & 1 \\
    27   & 0.3  &  0.5  & 0.1 \\
    13  &0.1   &0.9   &0.0002
\end{bmatrix}$$

Both have the same numbers for the row and column (all the data are in pandas dataframe).
What I want is the RMSD column by column so I should have 4 RMSD values.

The residual is obtained using python: `Residual=data1-data2`

`RMSD_term=((Residual)**2).sum(axis=0)`

```
RMSD=(((RMSD_term)/(3))**0.5)*100
```

Is this a correct approach?